# Conditions on a $1$-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for there to exist a function such that the form is closed.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

What are the conditions on a $1$-form in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for there to exist a function such that the form is closed? More precisely, given a point, $p$, what are conditions on the coefficients of a $1$-form $\omega$ so that there is a non-zero function, $\lambda$, such that $d(\lambda \omega)=0$ in some neighborhood of $p$. I can derive equations from the definitions, but is there an equation that doesn't rely on $\lambda$?

With work, this is equivalent to solving $f_i \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^j}-f_j \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^i}=\lambda (\dfrac{\partial f^j}{\partial x^i}-\dfrac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j})$ for $i,j\in \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Comment: why is the word exact in your title?

Comment: Because my mind switched it with exists! Thanks

Comment: @PaxKivimae See that the tag "differential-equations" is misleading.

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar A smooth function, sorry

Comment: @JesseMadnick True. I apologize.

Comment: $$f_i \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^j}-f_j \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^i}=\lambda (\dfrac{\partial f^j}{\partial x^i}-\dfrac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j})\\
f_i \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^j}-f_j \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^i}=\lambda \dfrac{\partial f^j}{\partial x^i}-\lambda\dfrac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j}\\
f_i \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^j}+\lambda\dfrac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j}=\lambda \dfrac{\partial f^j}{\partial x^i}+f_j \dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x^i}$$This is vaguely reminiscent of the product rule.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar because the exterior derivative satisfies the product rule: $d(\lambda \omega) = d\lambda \wedge \omega + \lambda d\omega$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A smooth function $\lambda$ such that $d(\lambda \omega) =0$ is called an ***integrating factor*** for $\omega$.  If $\omega$ is a nonvanishing $1$-form, then $\omega$ has a nonvanishing integrating factor in a neighborhood of each point if and only if $\omega\wedge d\omega=0$.

The necessity of this condition follows from the Poincaré lemma: If $d(\lambda\omega)=0$ and $\lambda$ doesn't vanish, then locally $\lambda\omega = du$ for some smooth function $u$, and substituting $\omega = \lambda^{-1}du$ leads to $\omega\wedge d\omega = 0$.

To prove sufficiency, assume $\omega\wedge d\omega = 0$.  Then [Cartan's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_lemma) shows that in a neighborhood of $p$ there is a smooth $1$-form $\beta$ such that $d\omega = \omega\wedge \beta$.  (This is easy to prove if you set $\omega^1=\omega$ and choose smooth $1$-forms $\omega^2,\dots, \omega^n$ near $p$ so that $(\omega^1,\dots,\omega^n)$ form a local coframe, and express $d\omega$ in terms of this coframe.) The Frobenius theorem then shows that locally there are smooth coordinates $(u^1,\dots,u^n)$ near $p$ such that $\omega = f\,du^1$ for some nonvanishing smooth function $f$, and we can take $\lambda = 1/f$ as an integrating factor.

Note that the condition $\omega\wedge d\omega = 0$ is always true on a $2$-manifold, because every $3$-form is zero. Thus every smooth nonvanishing $1$-form on a $2$-manifold has an integrating factor in a neighborhood of each point.

If $\omega$ vanishes somewhere, things get more complicated.  In that case, $\omega\wedge d\omega=0$ is necessary for the existence of a local integrating factor, but not sufficient.  A counterexample is provided by the form $\omega = y\,dx$ on $\mathbb R^2$. I don't know if there is a simple sufficient condition in this case.

Comment: How about zeros of $\lambda$ in yr proof of necessity? You seem to assume they don't exist.

Comment: @Gil Bor: Sorry, the OP had asked about a nonzero function $\lambda$, and that's what I was thinking about; but I forgot to state that in my proof. I'll fix it.